# What would be a good way to set up equivalent of Lua-for-Windows on Linux?

Tags: ide, lua, cross-platform, scite

My primary development environment is Linux (Debian particularly), but for various reasons, I began learning / using Lua (that too recently), in the Windows environment. I like the Lua-for-Windows (batteries-included) approach, and the SciTE IDE that ships with it, with the embedded debugging functionalities, over and above the plain-vanilla SciTE IDE.

On Linux however, having installed the standard Lua5.1 package on Debian via the standard apt repositories, I find that the IDE is missing.

Also, while I've not checked exhaustively, but I got the impression that not all the libraries (that'd make sense, since they are cross-platform) shipped with LfW, are available as part of the standard Lua5.1 package on Debian. How do I do an exhaustive check ?

Finally, to install any missing / additional libraries on Debian side, is LuaRocks the preferred and recommended approach ?

Comment: Luarocks has worked really well for me so far. Dunno about Scite though because I use another text editor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking for a Lua IDE to run on Linux, try [ZeroBrane Studio](http://studio.zerobrane.com). It's in many ways similar to SciTE as it's based on the same Scintilla editor and is available on Windows/Linux/OSX.

For installing libraries you need, I'd start with LuaRocks.

Comment: Just installed zbstudio, and so far liking it... in some way, even better than the IDE shippwed with LfW.

Answer (score 1):

As far as batteries are concerned, there are some major differences in several windows and linux release of various lua modules.

For the IDE, you can import `SciTEGlobal.properties` file to your own SciTE setup/directory in debian, or more importantly; the `user.toolbar` section. These lines are what make SciTE an IDE:

```
run|IDM_GO|Run Program|\
stop|IDM_STOPEXECUTE|Kill Program|\
terminal|lua;no;start_lua_prompt|Launch Interactive Lua|\
load|lua;yes;load_current_lua_file|Load Lua File into Interactive Session|\
|||\
debug|lua;yes;do_run|Debug Program/Continue|\
breakpoint|lua;no;do_breakpoint|Set Breakpoint|\
step|lua;no;do_step|Step|\
step_over|lua;no;do_next|Step Over|\
step_out|lua;no;do_finish|Step Out|\
watch|lua;no;do_watch|Watch Variable|\
inspect|lua;no;do_inspect|Inspect Variable|\
stack|lua;no;do_backtrace|Stack Trace|\
stopd|lua;no;do_kill|Stop Debugging|
```

Comment: Thanks @hjpotter92. What kind of differences were you alluding to when you wrote "major differences in several windows and linux release of various lua modules" ??

Comment: @icarus74 As an example, consider LuaSQL, which provides `getlastautoid()` only for Linux release and not the Windows one.